# Merging two dataframes into one (1:n)

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`. There's a 1:n-relationship between these two dataframes with `df2` having multiple entries for each entry in `df1`.

My goal is to merge these two dataframes so that all the rows in `df1` are repeated and that all the columns in `df2` are imported. The foreign key (FK) in `df2` refers to the primary key (PK) in `df1`

```
# example data:
df1 <- data.frame(PK = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                  varA = sample(5, replace=T),
                  varB = sample(5, replace=T))

df2 <- data.frame(FK = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4),
                  varC = seq(9),
                  varD = seq(9))
```

The dataframe should be like:

```
PK | FK | varA | varB | varC | varD
1    1    ...    ...    1      1
1    1    ...    ...    2      2
2    2    ...    ...    3      3
2    2    ...    ...    4      4
3    3    ...    ...    5      5
3    3    ...    ...    6      6
4    4    ...    ...    7      7
4    4    ...    ...    8      8
4    4    ...    ...    9      9
5    NA   ...    ...    NA     NA
```

All the entries in `df1` should be there, even if there is no corresponding entry in `df2` (varC and varD should be NA then)

Comment: With `dplyr` package : `df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = c("PK", "FK"))` maybe ?

Comment: do you need `merge(df1, df2)` ?

Comment: Also, your desired output doesn't match. `varC` and `varD` are a sequence from 1:9 in your example data. Also, when you use `sample`, please include `set.seed` so we can reproduce your data

Comment: @DimitriPetrenko : Error: `by` can't contain join column `FK` which is missing from LHS

Comment: @divibisan you are right, I corrected the desired output-dataframe above. There is no need to include `set.seed` as the values do not matter here.

Comment: @D.Studer You're right that it doesn't really matter here, but it's a good practice. It's nice to be able to show that the results we get with our answers match your desired answers exactly and makes it much easier to troubleshoot issues with them.

Comment: sorry, `df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = c("PK" =  "FK"))` or `left_join(df1, df2, by = c("PK" =  "FK"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the native R function merge()
https://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html

or use dplyr, which I personally prefer due to the more intuitive sql-like syntax:
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html?q=inner%20_%20j#join-types

Since you are referring to "PK" and "FK" you may prefer the second option, but will need to install and load the dplyr package first using commands

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
```

Comment: `merge()` is sort of SQL `UNION` , `dplyr::left_join()` is similar to SQL `LEFT JOIN`. They are for not the same case of use.